# How to display different content IF all of the search.results do not have item.featured_image in Shopify Theme's search.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I began working with a company that already had quite a complex theme built and live. On their collection pages and search page, the products that don't have a featured image don't get displayed. So when searching if all of the results are items that don't have featured images, all there is now is a blank space where products would be.

I'm wanting to know if it is possible in the `search.liquid` file to check if all the `search.results` are missing an `item.featured_image`, if that's true, then skip showing the results and display a message stating there's no results.

A stripped down example of the code now is as follows:

```
{% if search.performed %}
{% paginate search.results by 60 %}

{% if search.results == empty %}
<div class="row">
  <h2>Sorry! No Search Results</h2>
  <p>Your search for <strong>"{{ search.terms }}"</strong> didn't
 return any results.</p>
</div>

{% else %}

<div class="row">
  <h1>Search Results</h1>
  <p>{{ search.results_count }} Products match your search.</p>
  {% include 'pagination' %}
</div>


{% for item in search.results %}
  {% if item.featured_image == blank %}
    {% continue %}
  {% endif %}

  // looped code for each item with featured image.

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}

{% endif %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

----EDIT----

As HymnZ led me to find, simply creating a for loop to count the `items.featured_image == blank` and checking if that count matches `search.results_count` does the trick.

Replacing `{% if search.results == empty %}`, which determines if the No Results text will display, with the code below solves the problem.

```
{% assign items_blank = 0 %}
{% for item in search.results %}
  {% if item.featured_image == blank %}
    {% assign items_blank = items_blank | plus: 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if search.results == empty or items_blank == search.results_count %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line `{% if search.results == empty %}` with the following code

```
{% assign items_blank = 0 %}
{% for item in search.results %}
  {% if item.featured_image == blank %}
  {% assign items_blank = items_blank | plus: 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if search.results == empty or items_blank == search.results_count %}
```

Comment: Although your example didn't do what I needed, I was able to figure out what I needed from your example. The very last line should be:

`{% if search.results == empty or items_blank == search.results_count %}`

Comment: Yup. I missed "check all" part. It has been edited. Thank you for pointing it out.